# toplevel var statement with common vs. assignment statement with comma: why are they different

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer

I execute both of these statements in the browser console. But they give different results/have different side effects. I would like to know the specific reason why.

```
var a = 1,b; #success value of b is undefined
a = 1,b; #failure
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Declaring_and_initializing_two_variables

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected behavior.
`var a = 1,b;` is equivalent to

```
var a = 1;
var b;
```

`a = 1,b;` is equivalent to

```
a = 1;
b;
```

`b;` is not valid JS expression.
UPD: the previous statement is incorrect. `b;` is a reference to an undefined variable.

What's the reason to use variable declaration without `var` keyword? It will fail in strict mode.

Comment: The second one assigns `b` to `a`, not `1`.

Comment: Are you sure?
`var b = 3;`
`a = 1,b;`
`console.log(a);`
will output `1`.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I messed up precedence. Still, "*`b;` is not valid JS expression*" isn't entirely correct. (I can remove my downvote as soon as you edit, it's locked unfortunately)

Comment: Indeed b; is a valid expression, but it has to be assigned first, right?

Comment: I agree with you about `b;`. It's just a referencing to an undefined variable.

Comment: @tjb It has to be *declared* first

Answer (score 4):

Because the comma has a different meaning here. In the first statement, it separates [multiple variables to be declared](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) (with a single `var` keyword):

```
var a = 1,
    b /* = undefined */;
```

In the second statement, it's a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) separating two expressions:

```
(a = 1), b; /*
 ^       ^ Reference Error
 | declared above */
```

Comment: In the second statement, if the parenthesis are left out, (as they were in the question), then I think the the first value is  assigned to a, and the engine attempts to execute the second value and therefore it fails...thank you for your help in understanding this, but why is Oleksandr's answer below wrong.

Comment: @tjb that's was my answer but for some reason, it was downvoted.

Comment: @tjb Oops, fixed. Assignment has higher precendence than comma.